# Why is SKSpriteNode not working with SKAction?

Tags: swift, skspritenode, skaction

I'm working on a project and tried to reset the position with an `SKAction`, but the `SKSpriteNode` didn't move! Can anyone help?

```
import SpriteKit
import Foundation

enum Difficulty: TimeInterval {
    case easy = 8.5
    case normal = 6.0
    case hard = 4.0
    case extraHard = 2.0
}

class Note: SKSpriteNode {
    init() {
        super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "dropNotes"), color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: 50, height:  50))
        self.position = CGPoint(x: 375, y: 999)
    }

    func fall(difficulty: Difficulty) {
        let fallAction = SKAction.move(
            to: CGPoint(
                x: 375,
                y: 180
            ),
            duration: difficulty.rawValue
        )
        let resetAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 700), duration: 0.01)
        run(fallAction)
        run(resetAction)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this happpened? Please answer if you do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

Look at this part of your code

```
run(fallAction)
run(resetAction)
```

You are running these 2 actions at the **same time**. Instead I guess you want to run the `fallAction` and then, **AFTER** it finishes, the `resetAction` right?

### The fix

In this case you need to create a sequence and run it.

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fallAction, resetAction])
run(sequence)
```

### Full code

Here's the full fall method updated

```
func fall(difficulty: Difficulty) {
    let fallAction = SKAction.move(
        to: CGPoint(
            x: 375,
            y: 180
        ),
        duration: difficulty.rawValue
    )
    let resetAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 700), duration: 0.01)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fallAction, resetAction])
    run(sequence)
}
```